# Wrong text in cookie banner network-wide

Tags: bug, design

Researching stuff about Ubuntu, I noticed that the cookie banner there has the text of the one for Stack Overflow:

> This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service. Your use of **Stack Overflow**’s Products and Services, including the **Stack Overflow** Network, is subject to these policies and terms.

Also the links in the banner point to Stack Overflow.

Out of curiosity, I fired up some other SE sites (in incognito mode), and got the same wrong text, both on the main and meta sites.

### Repro steps

1. Fire up an incognito window in your browser
2. Go to any SE (meta) site except Area 51, for example [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) or [interpersonal.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com).
3. Now you can see it:
   [image: Wrong banner on Ask Ubuntu]

Comment: "Stack Overflow" is the public name of the company that runs the network. This terminology is correct.

Comment: @Catija I agree that is correct, but the term "Stack Overflow Network" is still incorrect IMO and the links point to SO instead to the specific SE site.

Comment: Ah, yeah... "Stack Overflow Network" is bad :P :D I might emphasize that over "Stack Overflow" generally. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the meantime, the message is currently:

> By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service.

The links still point to Stack Overflow, but since the Policies and the ToS are the same network-wide, I think that's acceptable